# Potential divider formula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

[image]

Hi, does applying resistance to a potential divider affect the output voltage? For example, if I were to put resistor R midway across a variable resistor would output voltage still = (R1/R1 + R2) x E? 
Picture is an example of what I mean, for example would the Pd across R still equal the Pd if R was replaced with a voltmeter or would rules change to account for the added resistance. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the concept of potential dividers but responses would be great.

P. A I edited this question in response to a comment and I apologise if this question sounds stupid because I couldn't find any information about this.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions. Can you try making a question about some concepts that you'd need to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to account for the added resistance. Here are some hints.

In a series loop the current at all points must be the same. The voltage drops across each branch of a parallel circuit must all be identical.

You have a pair of parallel resistors in series with a 3rd resistor. Find the equivalent resistance for the whole circuit, and thence the total current. Now use the current to calculate the voltage drop across the 3rd resistor.

Answer (score 0):

The formula: O/P Vol. = E x R1/(R1+R2) always applies, BUT R1 is equal to R in parallel with the part of the variable resistor (known as a potentiometer, or pot.) it is across. In this case:
o/p Vol = 9.6 x 200/(200+400) = 3.2V  The general formula for resistors in parallel is:[image]

Comment: Hi. You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/207316) to typeset mathematics. This makes equations look nicer, and it also makes it easier to search for them.